# How to make VirtualBox VM share case sensitive?

Tags: linux, filesystems, virtualbox, development-environment

As you all know, Linux filenames are case-sensitive whereas Windows (NTFS) are not. For our development systems, we use a Windows 10 host and a CentOS VM in VirutalBox. One thing VirtualBox can do is map your host drive to a virtual network share inside a Linux VM in VirtualBox, so that it can access the host filesystem when needed. When it does this, however, the filenames become case-insensitive:

```
[webadmin@localhost images]$ ll SurveyResultsBanner.png
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 18146 Aug 25  2015 SurveyResultsBanner.png 
[webadmin@localhost images]$ ll SURVEYRESULTSBANNER.PNG
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 18146 Aug 25  2015 SURVEYRESULTSBANNER.PNG 
[webadmin@localhost images]$ ll SuRvEyReSuLtSbAnNeR.PnG
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 18146 Aug 25  2015 SuRvEyReSuLtSbAnNeR.PnG
```

This case insensitivity extends to Apache as well, and it will happily serve up files in a case-insensitive manner.

This has bitten me a few times in my development environment where I accidentally include files or link to images with the wrong case. Everything looks great on Dev and then when it is pushed out it doesn't work, because the filename case differs.

Is there any way to make this "network share" be case-sensitive?

Comment: You could turn on case sensitivity in NTFS

Comment: This did not work when I tried it. The VM was still not case sensitive. I'm also very apprehensive about making such a drastic change my work PC to begin with; my bet is there are a lot of Windows programs that load libraries and may have the case wrong...

Comment: Indeed there are a lot of Windows programs that _assume_ that NTFS (and Windows in general) is case-insensitive. Even some Microsoft programs stop working. Without knowing more, I'd recommend setting up a separate Linux VM specifically to host your shared development files. Then you can mount that from both your host machine and from other machines.

Comment: You can turn on case sensitivity for a specific directory. So it's not that Windows necessarily breaks just because of that. I'm also using virtual box with a windows share and activated case senstivity on the shared directory, but the problem persists, as you already mentioned.