# Files under /var/www behaving in a case-insensitive way on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-14.04

I'm having trouble understanding what is going on here.  Under /var or ~/ or anywhere else in the file system I cannot access a file unless I am case sensitive (as expected).  However when I go into the /var/www directory (or  every other directory down from there) I can access the file in a case-insensitive way.

I can not reproduce this on my other systems so I'm thinking it must be a configuration that has been made on this box.  I just don't know where to look for it.

Can someone please help me track down why this is happening?

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var$ ls -l
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Apr 10  2014 backups
drwxr-xr-x 13 root    root    4096 Nov  8 03:20 cache
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Nov  8 03:18 chef
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4096 Nov  6 20:42 crash
drwxr-xr-x 53 root    root    4096 Nov  8 03:20 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root    staff   4096 Apr 10  2014 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root       9 Nov  6 20:40 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 13 root    syslog  4096 Nov  8 12:56 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root    mail    4096 Nov  6 20:40 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Nov  6 20:40 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root       4 Nov  6 20:40 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 Nov  6 20:41 spool
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant vagrant   28 Nov 17 13:22 thisIsATestFile.txt
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4096 Nov  6 20:43 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant  204 Nov 17 13:22 www
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var$ cat thisIsATestFile.txt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var$ cat THISISATESTFILE.txt 
cat: THISISATESTFILE.txt: No such file or directory
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var$ cd www
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 1394 Nov 17 13:08 html
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   81 Nov  8 02:28 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   28 Nov 17 13:21 thisIsATestFile.txt
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$ cat thisIsATestFile.txt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$ cat THISISATESTFILE.txt 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$
```

Here is the distribution info:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$ uname -r
3.13.0-135-generic
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$
```

Comment: is that a different file system? (that is mounted on /var/www)

Comment: I just checked and yes it is.  /var/www is vboxsf, /var is ext4.  Thank you, I think that may explain it.  vboxsf must have this case-insensitive property, right?

Comment: then duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460417/how-to-make-virtualbox-vm-share-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pointed out that you are using vboxsf file system for `/var/www` mount point.

This file system is not case sensitive by default.

Mabye see https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40423 if you want to mount it in a case sensitive way.